# Rails flash: concurrency problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cookies, flash-message

I have written and maintain a Rails forum software. In this software I redirect the user to the posting URL with a `notice` that the posting has been saved. Just before that I send a notification via a websocket to notify the users that a new posting or thread has arrived and the possibly in a different tab opened thread list can get updated. To update the thread list I do an AJAX request to the server and fetch the new, fresh thread tree.

This leads to the weird phenomenon that the flash doesn't clear after it gets displayed. It only clears when I close all tabs but one and do a manual reload. After a lot of debugging it seems to me that there is a race condition with the session cookie. Due to the AJAX request the flash gets set again and again:

- Request 1 clears the flash in the session cookie
- before Request 1 has been finished Request 2 starts with the old flash content in the session cookie
- when Request 1 has finished it sets the local cookie value to the new value
- Request 2 finishes and sets the local cookie value back to the old value

A temporary solution to the problem is to delay the AJAX request. This works, but is still vulnerable to the same race condition, depending on net speed. But I could not find a real solution to this problem; any suggestions?

Comment: Not a very easy solution but I'm thinking that [storing sessions server-side](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/) (e.g. in memcache or database) might help here.

That way, you'll always have only a single session defined for each user (client browser) and should not see these problems any more. But there are other drawbacks compared to cookie session store, see the linked article.

Comment: Tried sessions in memcached, but there is a race condition as well: Request a reads session. Request b reads session. Request a clears the flash and writes the session. Request b overwrites the session with old data. Are sessions in the database concurrency safe?

Comment: Hmm, I see, I guess you are right. Still thinking...